# shellexec and c:\program files - x86 and x64 portability

Tags: c, windows

I'm modifying an open-source GUI (written in c) to add a new menu item to the tray app. The new menu entry executes a file (update.exe) in the program root in c:\program files directory. Im using shellexec() and it works fine on x86, but since the path is different on x64 - c:\program files (x86), it fails to load. I'd like to use something to the effect of an environment variable like %programfiles%. What is an elegant solution to this?

Alternatively, I do have the ability to change where the update.exe file is stored. Putting it in 'program files' just seemed the most logical. For the problem above, should it go outside of program files? If so where?

Comment: This is automatic with file system redirection for 32-bit apps.  Try to diagnose "fails to load" better.

Comment: On x64, the application that is called simply does not load, I assume because it cannot be found due to a different path. If file-redirection is taking place, it is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GetModuleFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the full path to the executable. Then you'll just have to cut the filename from the end, and you'll have the complete directory path.

Something like this should to the trick:

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
LPTSTR szFileName;

GetModuleFileName(g_hInstance, szPath, sizeof(szPath)/sizeof(TCHAR));
szFileName = _tcsrchr(szPath, TEXT("\\"));
*szFileName = TEXT('\0');

// szPath now contains the path
```

(Warning! Untested!)

Comment: But if the program's directory is Program Files (x86), the system will re-map that to lie to you and say "Program Files".  Now, you might say that you can `SetCurrentDirectory` to the dir of the program before launching any command prompts...

Comment: @asveikau It will not, Windows never removes "(x86)". It might add "(x86)" when doing actual file access behind your back though.